# Getting IBDesignables error when using CocoaPods in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, ibdesignable

I have been working in some apps using cocoapods and somewhen when I compile them, I start to get errors with IBDesignables saying that the app failed to render and update autolayout status. Does anybody knows how to fix them?

[image: IBDesignable error]

Comment: Its an xcode bug, it may look odd but it won't cause the build to fail. Let it be there. Everyone needs a home.

Comment: set this code in your pod file and re-install pod                                
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
          config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
      end
end
end